# 'Series' object is not callable in mean temperature calculation

Tags: python, pandas, series

i am trying to calculate the mean temperature during the weekends. So i converted my date object to a datetime, and after i created a weekday column. But when i try to calculate the mean temperature it fails with this error 'Series' object is not callable

here is my code:

```
import numpy 
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt

def avg_weekend_temperature(df):
    df['DATEn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATEn'])
    df['weekday'] = df['DATEn'].dt.dayofweek()
    mean_temp_weekends = numpy.mean(df.meantempi[df.weekday == 5] or df.meantempi[df.weekday == 6])
    return mean_temp_weekends

avg_weekend_temperature(turnstile_weather)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-a808adfb4fbd> in <module>()
      9     return mean_temp_weekends
     10 
---> 11 avg_weekend_temperature(turnstile_weather)

<ipython-input-39-a808adfb4fbd> in avg_weekend_temperature(df)
      5 def avg_weekend_temperature(df):
      6     df['DATEn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATEn'])
----> 7     df['weekday'] = df['DATEn'].dt.dayofweek()
      8     mean_temp_weekends = numpy.mean(df.meantempi[df.weekday == 5] or df.meantempi[df.weekday == 6])
      9     return mean_temp_weekends

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

IESn_hourly EXITSn_hourly   maxpressurei    maxdewpti   ... meanpressurei   fog rain    meanwindspdi    mintempi    meantempi   maxtempi    precipi thunder weekday
0   0   R001    2011-05-01  01:00:00    1   REGULAR 0.0 0.0 30.31   42.0    ... 30.27   0.0 0.0 5.0 50.0    60.0    69.0    0.0 0.0 6
1   1   R001    2011-05-01  05:00:00    5   REGULAR 217.0   553.0   30.31   42.0    ... 30.27   0.0 0.0 5.0 50.0    60.0    69.0    0.0 0.0 6
2   2   R001    2011-05-01  09:00:00    9   REGULAR 890.0   1262.0  30.31   42.0    ... 30.27   0.0 0.0 5.0 50.0    60.0    69.0    0.0 0.0 6
3   3   R001    2011-05-01  13:00:00    13  REGULAR 2451.0  3708.0  30.31   42.0    ... 30.27   0.0 0.0 5.0 50.0    60.0    69.0    0.0 0.0 6
4   4   R001    2011-05-01  17:00:00    17  REGULAR 4400.0  2501.0  30.31   42.0    ... 30.27   0.0 0.0 5.0 50.0    60.0    69.0    0.0 0.0 6
5 rows × 23 columns
```

What do you think?
I think the problem is in the 'or' because when i write:

```
numpy.mean(turnstile_weather.meantempi[turnstile_weather.weekday == 5])
67.020761245674734
numpy.mean(turnstile_weather.meantempi[turnstile_weather.weekday == 6])
63.573329051791369
```

the problem is that i can't put them together

Comment: Maybe your intent was to write `df['weekday'] = dt.dayofweek(df['DATEn'])`? Or maybe `df['DATEn'].dt.dayofweek` (without the parens)?

Comment: just tried. same result

Comment: It is `df['DATEn'].dt.dayofweek` (without the parentheses).

Comment: without parens i get this - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Without parens, and also you need to change the next line to: `mean_temp_weekends = numpy.mean(df.meantempi[df.weekday == 5] | df.meantempi[df.weekday == 6])`. You need to use bitwise OR to compare Series.

Comment: That's a different error from a different line. `numpy.mean(df.meantempi[df.weekday == 5] or df.meantempi[df.weekday == 6])` should be `df.meantemp[(df.weekday==5) | (df.weekday==6)].mean()`

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'bool'

Comment: Reading your sample data gives me the error "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 15 fields in line 2, saw 22" using "pd.read_csv('/tmp/hd1.tsv', delim_whitespace=True" -- please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i finally managed to find the correct answer.
This is the code:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def avg_weekend_temperature(df):
    df['DATEn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATEn'])
    df['weekday'] = df['DATEn'].dt.dayofweek
    mean_temp_weekends = numpy.mean(df.meantempi[(df.weekday == 5) | (df.weekday == 6)])
    return mean_temp_weekends

avg_weekend_temperature(turnstile_weather)
```

Thanks everybody